# Understanding MPI multi-host mode

Tags: performance, multiprocessing, mpi, host

I have two hosts with the same number of cores (20 = 10 virtual + 10 real).

Just to test my MPI performance I use simple matrix multiplication program.

I understand MPI with two hosts as "let's start maximum cores in every host"

The problem is the following:

- In one-node mode I execute `mpirun -n 20 mm` and obtain executed time nearly 0.5 sec.
- Then in multi-node mode I execute `mpirun -n 20 --host srv1:20,srv2:20 mm` and obtain time nearly 0.5 sec too.

So there are no better performance with two hosts usage (but it's expected).

What settings, options, configuration files (and so on) I should check&repair to get expected result?

Thanks.

Comment: in the second case, it is likely the 20 MPI tasks end up running on the same host! Run 40 MPI tasks, declare 10 slots on each node, or ask `mpirun` to use both nodes to see a difference.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, thanks for response! If I understand you correctly, I should use smth like `mpirun -n 40 --oversubscribe --host srv1:10,srv2:10 mm`, but it has executed nearly ~4.3 sec

Comment: Depending on what you want to measure, run 40 MPI tasks with 20+20 slots **or** run 20 MPI takks with 10+10 slots.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, unfortunately there are no better performance at all. Both of your cases work much slower (more than 3 or 4 secs)...

Comment: Inter node communication generally have a higher latency and a lower bandwidth compared to intra node communications. Depending on your algorithm and dataset size, going multi node is not always the fastest option.